# シェルスクリプト内のエイリアスコマンドを実行したい

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript

`~/.bash_aliases` であらかじめ以下のエイリアスを設定しておき、

```
alias ll='ls -l'
```

`~/bin/rootls.sh` にてエイリアスを用いたコマンドを実行しようとしています。

```
#!/bin/bash
ll /
```

端末で以下のように実行したのですが、エイリアスが読み込まれていないようでした。

```
$ BASH_ENV=~/.bash_aliases
$ bash -O expand_aliases rootls.sh
/home/naomeo0/bin/rootls.sh: 行 2: ll: コマンドが見つかりません
```

なぜこのような結果になるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1行でまとめて実行するか、

```sh
$ BASH_ENV=~/.bash_aliases bash -O expand_aliases ~/bin/rootls.sh
```

`export` で環境変数 BASH_ENV を設定してから実行してみてください。

```sh
$ export BASH_ENV=~/.bash_aliases
$ bash -O expand_aliases ~/bin/rootls.sh
```

---

export を付けず単に `BASH_ENV=~/.bash_aliases` を実行しただけでは、コマンド実行後に設定が残りません。

```sh
$ printenv BASH_ENV
$                            # 事前に何も設定されていないことを確認

$ BASH_ENV=~/.bash_aliases
$ printenv BASH_ENV
$                            # 設定は残らない
```